# Getting error in browser console- Uncaught ReferenceError: allauth is not defined

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

I have been trying to use allauth (facebook js sdk) with my django project. So I put the below lines.
Setting file code:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
'facebook': {
    'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
    'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile'],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
    'INIT_PARAMS': {'cookie': True},
    'FIELDS': ['id','email'],
    'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
    #'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable',
    'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True,
    'VERSION': 'v2.12',
  }
}
```

layout file code:

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Facebook 
Connect</a>
```

Getting below error in browser console when I am trying to connect with facebook.
Uncaught ReferenceError: allauth is not defined.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error because of fbconnect.js file was not attaching and getting another error in console "Refused to execute script from 'https://www.localhost/static/facebook/js/fbconnect.js' because its MIME type ('image/png') is not executable." so I forcefully attached fbconnect.js in header.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if django_allauth is installed or not.

Maybe you installed it in a virtual environment but you have not activated it. Or maybe it's the other way round.

Comment: Vipin django_allauth already installed. If I am trying without method="js_sdk" then its working fine and redirecting from my website to facebook and I want to open facebook in popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Add `allauth` in **INSTALL_APPS** in `settings.py`

ALso this help you [django-allauth Uncaught ReferenceError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994900/django-allauth-uncaught-referenceerror)

Comment: also reviewed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994900/django-allauth-uncaught-referenceerror) but no luck

Comment: Oh. Sorry I can't help.